# Html: Why is the label inside the checkbox after setting the display to inline?

Tags: html, css

I think its because of `display: flex;` how can I make the label on same row as the checkbox? also why is the checkbox not centered?

```css
.options_display {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.options_style * {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: medium;
    font-family: arial;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 25px;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
    margin: 0px;
}

[hidden] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Kalkulačka</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/Main.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="float: left; position: relative; left: 50%;">
            <div style="float: left; position: relative; left: -50%;">
                <div class="options_display options_style">
                    <select>
                        <option>Select test</option>
                        <option>Option 0</option>
                        <option>Option 1</option>
                        <option>Option 2</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="Input test">
                    <div style="display: inline;">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="test">
                        <label for="test">Test</label>  
                    </div>
                    <button onclick="">Button test</button>
                    <p>Text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the label not inside the checkbox?

It's because the style rules from `.options_style *` are applied to both the label and the checkbox, that style rule specified the width to elements they apply to. Thus, in this case, both the checkbox and the label has `225px` width, and since their parent has `display: inline`, while the elements are not inline and have widths more than the container, one of them will have to go to the new line. A quick fix would be to change that `display: inline` to `display: flex`, and make the `width` property of the label and the checkbox to be `auto`. But to make it a bit better I also added some improvement of the stylings on my code below.

```css
.options_display {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.options_style * {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: medium;
    font-family: arial;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 25px;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
    margin: 0px;
}

[hidden] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Kalkulačka</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/Main.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="float: left; position: relative; left: 50%;">
            <div style="float: left; position: relative; left: -50%;">
                <div class="options_display options_style">
                    <select>
                        <option>Select test</option>
                        <option>Option 0</option>
                        <option>Option 1</option>
                        <option>Option 2</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="Input test">
                    <div style="display: flex;margin: 0 auto;justify-content: center;align-items: center;">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="test" style="width: auto">
                        <label for="test" style="width: auto; height: auto">Test</label>  
                    </div>
                    <button onclick="">Button test</button>
                    <p>Text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
.options_style option {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: medium;
   font-family: arial;
   padding: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 2px;
   width: 225px;
   height: 25px;
}
```

apply the above mentioned class ".options_style" only to the "option" of "select" element not to all the contents of "div" element.

Comment: Code only answers "can help" but the only provide the code, please make sure you include why / where / how and the explanations for this

Comment: just copied his class, with 0 explaination about what you are doing.

Comment: i have modified the class selector from ".options_style" to ".options_ style  option" which indicates that class style properties only gets applied to "option" element. I hope this comment solves issue